# Specify Thumbnail Dimensions in Microdata for RichSnippets

Tags: microdata, schema.org, rich-snippets

I added metadata tags for our products as specified by http://schema.org, for use by RichSnippets, etc...

It works great except that our products only have 3x2 images, and google resizes them to square for the RichSnippets, which causes them to look terrible.

I've seen examples where 
Is there a way to specify the dimensions of an image tagged as `itemprop="thumbnailUrl"` (or `itemprop="image"`) without changing the image's actual size?

Edit: injecting PageMap (as seen in http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1626955) data didn't work for me, as the rest of the page is done with microdata.

Edit: My object is http://schema.org/Recipe, which doesn't include `width` or `height` for its `thumbnailUrl` object.

Comment: Note: PageMap is only for Google’s Custom Search.

Answer (score 3):

Make a copy of your thumbnail images resized or cropped to look fine as a square, as this is what SE will show, then use the meta tag with content to specify using those thumbnails instead of the ones you show on your webpages.
e.g.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe">
..
<meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="http://my/optimized/thumbnail/url.png" />
<image src="http://this/is/the/thumbnail/not/resized.png" />
..
</div>
```